# Visual Studio Team Services Building JSON Scripts

Tags: json, azure-devops, selenium-builder

I'm currently building scripts using Selenium Builder (which saves files as JSON) and i'm having a hard time running these scripts on VSTS. My question specifically is, can Visual Studio Team Services build JSON scripts and tie them in with its C.I.? If so, which approach must I take in order to do this / make it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your Json script works for? If it combined with nodejs or grunt, you can used related build template. Else, you can develop the build tasks/template for your own needs, example you can refer: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/fabrikam-build-extension

Comment: The JSON scripts are for automation testing (Selenium). I can export them as .cs but I was hoping to avoid adding that extra layer of work because there will be hundreds, if not thousands of scripts. Do you know of any tutorials I can refer to that will guide me into understanding how to make my own templates for JSON files?

Comment: How do you build scripts on you local machine? Can you share the detailed steps so that we can check if these steps can be run with VSTS?

Comment: When you run a Selenium Builder script it uses an interpreter. Jenkins provides a plugin that uses that uses that same interpreter to check/utilize the JSON script.

 Interpreter link: https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/SeInterpreter-Java/blob/master/sebuilder-interpreter.iml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my steps for your reference:

1. Deploy your own private build agent by following [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows).
2. Configure the required environment on the build agent like Selenium Driver, Firefox so that the testing can be run on the build agent.
3. Upload the json file generated by Selenium Builder into VSTS Repository.
4. Create a build definition with two Command Line tasks: The first one runs npm install command to install se-interpreter:
   [image]
   And the second one run se-interpreter command to run the test in json file:
   [image]
5. Queue the build, you will see the test been executed during the build:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question!